# Execution of then() function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am new to asynchronous JavaScript, while learning Promise in JavaScript, I wrote a simple program

```
var p=new Promise(function(resolve,reject)
{
  //Any async task.
  var IsPromiseFulfilled=true;

  if(IsPromiseFulfilled){
    resolve("Promise Fulfilled");
  }
  else
  {
    reject("Promise Rejected");
  }
});

p.then(function(status){
  console.log(status);
}).catch(function(status){
  console.log(status);
});

console.log("End Of Program");
```

The Output was:

```
End Of Program
Promise Fulfilled
```

Can anyone please tell me why "End Of Program" was printed earlier than "Promise Fulfilled"

Comment: because asynchronous code remains asynchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works this way because of the way `.then()` handlers are described in the [promise specification](https://promisesaplus.com/).

All `.then()` handlers are executed on a future tick of the event loop.  That means that any synchronous code executes before any `.then()` handler even if the promise is resolved immediately.

Here's a very simple example:

```
console.log("a");
Promise.resolve().then(() => {console.log("b");});
console.log("c");
```

This will output:

```
 a
 c
 b
```

This is per the promise specification and it is done this way to guarantee that `.then()` handler are ALWAYS asynchronous and thus have a consistent and predictable behavior, regardless of whether the promise is resolved immediately or some time in the future.  It makes writing and testing code a lot simpler.

From the [Promises A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/):

> 2.2.4 onFulfilled or onRejected must not be called until the execution context stack contains only platform code. [3.1].

"platform code" here means that the current execution of Javascript finishes and then when the stack is completely empty of any Javascript, then and only then are promises `.then()` handlers called.

So, in my example above, the promise is resolved immediately, and the `.then()` handler is scheduled immediately, but it is scheduled to run AFTER the rest of the synchronous code finishes (essentially on the next turn of the event loop).

In the ES6 specification, when a promise resolves, its `.then()` handlers are scheduled with `enqueJob()`.  The concept of jobs in ES6 is described [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues).  What's relevant here is that they run AFTER the currently executing Javascript is done.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's executed outside of your promises and in turn executes before the promises resolve.

Although the `Promise.resolve().then()` call isn't slow, it will process all the code then start resolving the promises.

It's also worth noting you can shorten things a little as well by using promises like:

```
Promise.resolve().then(result => {
  // do something with your result
}).catch(error => {
  // do something with your error.
});
```

I find this format easier than using `new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {})`

Answer (score 1):

p.then happens in the future.  While node waits for the then promise to resolve it will execute the next line of code.

Which is the console.log("End Of Program");

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute your `Promises` and `async` functions in a linear way, you must use the

> ES2017 `async/await` syntax

Any Promise inside a async function can use the syntax `await`, for that you don't have to use `.then()` or `.catch()`

```
(async function () {
    try {
        var status = await p()

        console.log(status)
        console.log("End Of Program")
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e) //If p reject, you catch it here
    }

})()
```

And you should write your `Promise` like this

```
var p = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    /*  When you use asynchronous functions, they all have a callback
        This callback may have some error and data params, so,
        you use them to resolve or reject your promise
    */
    someAsyncFunction('blabla', function(error, data) {
        if (error)
            reject(error)
        else 
            resolve(data)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't pretend for academic answer but I already asked  [amost the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48134533/move-object-variable-away-from-async-function)
 today, about promises.

Actuall answer is:

> When you ask to do work in JS, what is says that, "OK, this is going to take some time, but I promise that I'll let you know after the work is done. So please have faith on my promise, I'll let you know once the work is complete", and it immediately gives you a promise to you.

That's why you see your:

```
End Of Program
Promise Fullfilled
```

The actuall scheme looks like this:

```
   │
   ├┐
   │↓ promise
   ↓
console.log
```